# Replace Save As path in existing macro

Tags: vba, excel

We have inherited someone else's spreadsheets and macros and simply want to update the path where it is saving the file.  We have been able to do this on every other spreadsheet, but this one is written differently and just updating the path itself isn't work.  Can someone please explain what is happening in the below code that is preventing us and/or how we can update the save as path?

```
Sub SpecialPaste()

' SpecialPaste Macro
' Macro recorded 12/9/02 by TPC

mySpecialPaste = InputBox(Prompt:="File Name?", _
       Title:="ENTER THE Save Name", Default:="LCY XXX 2013")

If mySpecialPaste = vbNo Then
    Exit Sub
ElseIf mySpecialPaste = vbYes Then
    Dim mysheet As Worksheet
    Set mysheet = Worksheets(1)
    mysheet.SaveAs FileName:="N:\All Users Desktop\Mthly Form Records\Mo BD Logs\BD Log 2013\BD Log Mar 13"
    mysheet.Unprotect "snowbird"
End If

Range("B6:H36").Select
Range("G6").Activate
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 6
Range("E2").Select
Set mysheet = Worksheets(1)
mysheet.Select
mysheet.Protect "snowbird", True, True, True

End Sub
```

Comment: What sort of error are you seeing (if any) and on what line? Also, the extension of your "FileName:=" is missing the extension at the end? (i.e. .xlsx)

Comment: There isn't any error, it just isn't saving the file anywhere that we can find.  The current SaveAs FileName is from the old user who is no longer with us.  We want to save it to the public drive which for us is K.  It runs as I expect it should, with the display box asking for the File Name, just can't sort out the location.

Comment: @Chrismas007 thank you for the edit.  I am new here and couldn't figure out how to get it all to display in the box.  Is it something obvious that I could do right next time?

Comment: I'm reading N:\all users desktop..." so I assume that the user in question had a network drive (N) mapping to somewhere.  There's no way that I know of (though I'm not an admin anymore) of finding out where a user had drive mappings to, (unless you can still log on to their profile?),  but if you search all the network storage locations for the path "\All users desktop\etc.," you might find it.

Comment: It shouldn't matter where the file used to be saved to.  Changing the path listed in the `Filename:=` parameter to your `K:\<path here>\ ` ought to be all that you need.  The `InputBox` just prompts for the file name to be saved, although it doesn't appear to then be used in the actual SaveAs?

Comment: What happens when you step through the process using the F8 key?

Comment: @Dave We have tried changing it to:

        Set mysheet = Worksheets(1)
            mysheet.SaveAs FileName:="K:\BDT"

And have tried both leaving the default in the InputBox and changing it to TEST.  We have not been able to locate the file anywhere.

Comment: @Hrothgar the original user was not on our network, we have just inherited their spreadsheets.  We are in the process of migrating everything and are trying to repoint to our network.

Comment: @Dave Stepping through using F8 opens the InputBox and allows you to edit the entry and click OK or Cancel, beyond that it doesn't appear to do anything that I can see.  That being said, I don't know what else this should be doing because we don't know what the rest means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the following code:

```
If mySpecialPaste = vbNo Then
    Exit Sub
ElseIf mySpecialPaste = vbYes Then
    Dim mysheet As Worksheet
    Set mysheet = Worksheets(1)
    mysheet.SaveAs FileName:="N:\All Users Desktop\Mthly Form Records\Mo BD Logs\BD Log 2013\BD Log Mar 13"
    mysheet.Unprotect "snowbird"
End If
```

to

```
If mySpecialPaste = "" Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    Dim mysheet As Worksheet
    Set mysheet = Worksheets(1)
    mysheet.SaveAs FileName:="K:\BDT\" & mySpecialPaste & ".xlsx"
    mysheet.Unprotect "snowbird"
End If
```

The `If..End If` block never gets executed as the response from the InputBox is never going to be `vbYes` or `vbNo`.  The `mySpecialPaste` variable is set to the value from the InputBox.  So if it's empty, then exit the Sub, otherwise save the file to your required location with the given filename.

Comment: It worked!  Thank you so much for not only solving it but also explaining, makes perfect sense!  Thank you!!!